# Elsa Document Approval Workflow (using VIsual Designer) always return 400

Tags: elsa-workflows

I am following Elsa Workflow tutorial here: https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/guides/guides-document-approval#document-approval-workflow-visual-designer

I am using the docker version, which should be the latest.

But whenever I sent a POST request using postman, it always returns `400`.

I believe I am following the tutorial exactly as described.

The **workflow isn't being triggered at all**..., I suspect `http://localhost:13000/v2/documents` is not the correct url.

Here is what I have designed.

[image]

This is what I POST using Postman.

[image]

This is the exported workflow definition.

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "definitionId": "94e1b452fe8e4239aeff1cf779a65329",
  "versionId": "cb2fbcfe31c44875b6f82b01ef477ea9",
  "name": "VisualDocumentApprovalWorkflow",
  "displayName": "Visual Document Approval Workflow",
  "version": 3,
  "variables": {
    "$id": "2",
    "data": {}
  },
  "customAttributes": {
    "$id": "3",
    "data": {}
  },
  "isSingleton": false,
  "persistenceBehavior": "WorkflowBurst",
  "deleteCompletedInstances": false,
  "isPublished": true,
  "isLatest": true,
  "createdAt": "2022-11-23T08:43:45.6472218Z",
  "activities": [
    {
      "$id": "4",
      "activityId": "b1d82194-6a6b-4568-adde-382b16027c93",
      "type": "HttpEndpoint",
      "displayName": "HTTP Endpoint",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "5",
          "name": "Path",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "6",
            "Literal": "/v2/documents/"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "7",
          "name": "Methods",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "8",
            "Json": "[\"POST\"]"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "9",
          "name": "ReadContent",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "10",
            "Literal": "true"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "11",
          "name": "TargetType",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "12"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "13",
          "name": "Schema",
          "syntax": "Literal",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "14",
            "Literal": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "15",
          "name": "Authorize",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "16",
            "Literal": "false"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "17",
          "name": "Policy",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "18",
            "Literal": "adaa"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "19"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "20",
      "activityId": "2e7f8800-d49f-4485-b47b-0c9f3cb82a48",
      "type": "SetVariable",
      "displayName": "Set Variable",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "21",
          "name": "VariableName",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "22",
            "Literal": "Document"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "23",
          "name": "Value",
          "syntax": "JavaScript",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "24",
            "Literal": "input.Body",
            "JavaScript": "input.Body"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "25"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "26",
      "activityId": "b10ffb0d-c9ae-439a-86fa-b4351294666d",
      "type": "SendEmail",
      "displayName": "Send Email",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "27",
          "name": "From",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "28",
            "Literal": "workflow@acme.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "29",
          "name": "To",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "30",
            "Json": "[\"josh@acme.com\"]"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "31",
          "name": "Subject",
          "syntax": "Liquid",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "32",
            "Literal": "Document received from {{Variables.Document.Author.Name}}",
            "Liquid": "Document received from {{Variables.Document.Author.Name}}"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "33",
          "name": "Attachments",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "34"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "35",
          "name": "Body",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "36",
            "Literal": "Document from {{ Variables.Document.Author.Name }} received for review.<br><a href=\"{{ \"Approve\" | signal_url }}\">Approve</a> or <a href=\"{{ \"Reject\" | signal_url }}\">Reject</a>"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "37",
          "name": "Cc",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "38"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "39",
          "name": "Bcc",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "40"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "41"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "42",
      "activityId": "90942864-bd26-4309-82fd-51f27b8e3615",
      "type": "WriteHttpResponse",
      "displayName": "HTTP Response",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "43",
          "name": "Content",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "44",
            "Literal": "<h1>Request for Approval Sent</h1><p>Your document has been received and will be reviewed shortly.</p>"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "45",
          "name": "ContentType",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "46",
            "Literal": "text/html"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "47",
          "name": "StatusCode",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "48",
            "Literal": "OK"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "49",
          "name": "CharSet",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "50",
            "Literal": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "51",
          "name": "ResponseHeaders",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "52"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "53"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "54",
      "activityId": "c62c8ff0-db76-4dea-b1a6-6cc138415b17",
      "type": "Fork",
      "displayName": "Fork",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "55",
          "name": "Branches",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "56",
            "Json": "[\"Approve\",\"Reject\",\"Remind\"]"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "57"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "58",
      "activityId": "aa201fb5-a50f-44b1-989f-7a7b57b3b52d",
      "type": "SignalReceived",
      "displayName": "Signal Received",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "59",
          "name": "Signal",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "60",
            "Literal": "Approve"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "61"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "62",
      "activityId": "615f0e0d-9f7a-4a2f-ab9e-97b3bea10cbe",
      "type": "SendEmail",
      "displayName": "Send Email",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "63",
          "name": "From",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "64",
            "Literal": "workflow@acme.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "65",
          "name": "To",
          "syntax": "JavaScript",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "66",
            "Json": "[\"[Document.Author.Email]\"]",
            "JavaScript": "[Document.Author.Email]"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "67",
          "name": "Subject",
          "syntax": "Liquid",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "68",
            "Liquid": "Document {{ Variables.Document.Id }} Approved!"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "69",
          "name": "Attachments",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "70"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "71",
          "name": "Body",
          "syntax": "Liquid",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "72",
            "Liquid": "Great job {{ Variables.Document.Author.Name }}, that document is perfect."
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "73",
          "name": "Cc",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "74"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "75",
          "name": "Bcc",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "76"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "77"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "78",
      "activityId": "af52dae7-254b-4602-be35-0c0ef23a4ba5",
      "type": "SignalReceived",
      "displayName": "Signal Received",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "79",
          "name": "Signal",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "80",
            "Literal": "Reject"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "81"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "82",
      "activityId": "ce2c17ff-cb9e-430a-a11e-9c92f0f4aa46",
      "type": "SendEmail",
      "displayName": "Send Email",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "83",
          "name": "From",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "84",
            "Literal": "workflow@acme.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "85",
          "name": "To",
          "syntax": "JavaScript",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "86",
            "JavaScript": "[Document.Author.Email]"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "87",
          "name": "Subject",
          "syntax": "Liquid",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "88",
            "Literal": "Document {{ Variables.Document.Id }} Rejected",
            "JavaScript": "Document {{ Variables.Document.Id }} Rejected"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "89",
          "name": "Attachments",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "90"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "91",
          "name": "Body",
          "syntax": "Liquid",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "92",
            "Liquid": "Nice try {{ Variables.Document.Author.Name }}, but that document needs work."
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "93",
          "name": "Cc",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "94"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "95",
          "name": "Bcc",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "96"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "97"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "98",
      "activityId": "0be8d291-f88e-4db6-866e-fc722df70b27",
      "type": "Timer",
      "displayName": "Timer",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "99",
          "name": "Timeout",
          "syntax": "JavaScript",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "100",
            "JavaScript": "Duration.FromSeconds(10)"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "101"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "102",
      "activityId": "01b73005-d48e-46eb-88ae-55a08f96c356",
      "type": "SendEmail",
      "displayName": "Send Email",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "103",
          "name": "From",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "104",
            "Literal": "workflow@acme.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "105",
          "name": "To",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "106",
            "Json": "[\"josh@acme.com\"]"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "107",
          "name": "Subject",
          "syntax": "Liquid",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "108",
            "Liquid": "{{ Variables.Document.Author.Name }} is waiting for your review!"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "109",
          "name": "Attachments",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "110"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "111",
          "name": "Body",
          "syntax": "Liquid",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "112",
            "Liquid": "Don't forget to review document {{ Variables.Document.Id }}.<br><a href=\"{{ \"Approve\" | signal_url }}\">Approve</a> or <a href=\"{{ \"Reject\" | signal_url }}\">Reject</a>"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "113",
          "name": "Cc",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "114"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "115",
          "name": "Bcc",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "116"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "117"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "118",
      "activityId": "e1c0aedb-c75b-4386-a20a-b0121f3a1421",
      "type": "Join",
      "displayName": "Join",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "119",
          "name": "EagerJoin",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "120"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "121",
          "name": "Mode",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "122",
            "Literal": "WaitAny"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "123"
      }
    },
    {
      "$id": "124",
      "activityId": "84247af4-66a8-41ab-a442-b72b1d256154",
      "type": "WriteHttpResponse",
      "displayName": "HTTP Response",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "125",
          "name": "Content",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "126",
            "Literal": "Thanks for the hard work!"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "127",
          "name": "ContentType",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "128",
            "Literal": "text/html"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "129",
          "name": "StatusCode",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "130",
            "Literal": "OK"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "131",
          "name": "CharSet",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "132",
            "Literal": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "133",
          "name": "ResponseHeaders",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "134"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {
        "$id": "135"
      }
    }
  ],
  "connections": [
    {
      "$id": "136",
      "sourceActivityId": "b1d82194-6a6b-4568-adde-382b16027c93",
      "targetActivityId": "2e7f8800-d49f-4485-b47b-0c9f3cb82a48",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "137",
      "sourceActivityId": "2e7f8800-d49f-4485-b47b-0c9f3cb82a48",
      "targetActivityId": "b10ffb0d-c9ae-439a-86fa-b4351294666d",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "138",
      "sourceActivityId": "b10ffb0d-c9ae-439a-86fa-b4351294666d",
      "targetActivityId": "90942864-bd26-4309-82fd-51f27b8e3615",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "139",
      "sourceActivityId": "90942864-bd26-4309-82fd-51f27b8e3615",
      "targetActivityId": "c62c8ff0-db76-4dea-b1a6-6cc138415b17",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "140",
      "sourceActivityId": "c62c8ff0-db76-4dea-b1a6-6cc138415b17",
      "targetActivityId": "aa201fb5-a50f-44b1-989f-7a7b57b3b52d",
      "outcome": "Approve"
    },
    {
      "$id": "141",
      "sourceActivityId": "aa201fb5-a50f-44b1-989f-7a7b57b3b52d",
      "targetActivityId": "615f0e0d-9f7a-4a2f-ab9e-97b3bea10cbe",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "142",
      "sourceActivityId": "c62c8ff0-db76-4dea-b1a6-6cc138415b17",
      "targetActivityId": "af52dae7-254b-4602-be35-0c0ef23a4ba5",
      "outcome": "Reject"
    },
    {
      "$id": "143",
      "sourceActivityId": "af52dae7-254b-4602-be35-0c0ef23a4ba5",
      "targetActivityId": "ce2c17ff-cb9e-430a-a11e-9c92f0f4aa46",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "144",
      "sourceActivityId": "c62c8ff0-db76-4dea-b1a6-6cc138415b17",
      "targetActivityId": "0be8d291-f88e-4db6-866e-fc722df70b27",
      "outcome": "Remind"
    },
    {
      "$id": "145",
      "sourceActivityId": "0be8d291-f88e-4db6-866e-fc722df70b27",
      "targetActivityId": "01b73005-d48e-46eb-88ae-55a08f96c356",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "146",
      "sourceActivityId": "01b73005-d48e-46eb-88ae-55a08f96c356",
      "targetActivityId": "0be8d291-f88e-4db6-866e-fc722df70b27",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "147",
      "sourceActivityId": "615f0e0d-9f7a-4a2f-ab9e-97b3bea10cbe",
      "targetActivityId": "e1c0aedb-c75b-4386-a20a-b0121f3a1421",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "148",
      "sourceActivityId": "ce2c17ff-cb9e-430a-a11e-9c92f0f4aa46",
      "targetActivityId": "e1c0aedb-c75b-4386-a20a-b0121f3a1421",
      "outcome": "Done"
    },
    {
      "$id": "149",
      "sourceActivityId": "e1c0aedb-c75b-4386-a20a-b0121f3a1421",
      "targetActivityId": "84247af4-66a8-41ab-a442-b72b1d256154",
      "outcome": "Done"
    }
  ],
  "id": "cb2fbcfe31c44875b6f82b01ef477ea9"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind..., the correct url is `http://localhost:13000/workflows/v2/documents` instead of `http://localhost:13000/v2/documents`.

I found this by trial and error.

I will submit a PR to amend the documentation.